# Will I lose my Salesforce Accredited Professional (AP) Credentials if I leave the company?

Tags: certification

I am planning to complete few certifications, would like to do the certification which will last longer :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can keep them. Please see the content from [Accredited Professional partner documentation](https://partners.salesforce.com/pdx/s/learn/article/accredited-professional-MCBQXAKQTOTZCQHOXTMK33NUMLWY?language=en_US).

> Accredited Professional credentials (in addition to all PLC enrollment and completion) can move with you to the new partner firm. Please open a support case here so we can transfer your achievements. Each credential will need to be maintained by completing maintenance content in PLC at least once a year. If your new employer is not part of the Salesforce partner program, you won’t have access to PLC and won’t be able to maintain the credential.